# Stop Nemo from opening as root

Tags: root, dolphin, nemo

When in Dolphin, I ask to open a folder in Nemo, and it only opens the folder as root.  How do I stop Dolphin from opening as root.  Dolphin also opens folders in Nautilus as root.

Comment: How are you opening `dolphin`?  If I open dolphin with sudo it opens all the other applications as root and gives me the error.

Comment: This problem happens, when I am in KFind.  KFind lists the files/folders that are found, and has an option to open the folder, which it does with Dolphin.  I like to use Nemo as the file manager, so I ask Dolphin to open the folder with Nemo, but it only will open it as root.